# Angularjs: how to update my model only once

Tags: angularjs, directive

I need to update my model after is has loaded its data. So i tried to write a directive which can do that. I didn't thought it would be this hard :(

I first tried a filter, which should be more simple, but got this error.

```
Error: [ngModel:nonassign] Expression 'editpage.url | addUrl' is non-assignable.
```

So now i try the directive way. This is my html code in the view:

```
<input ng-model="editpage.url" add-url type="text" class="light_txtbox" readonly>
```

And this is my directive:

```
app.directive('addUrl', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return;

            // what to do next?
        }
    };
}]);
```

In the "what to do next" part i tried a watch like this:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(site) {
                if (typeof site !== undefined) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue('www.mysite.com/' + site);
                    ngModel.$render();
                }
            });
```

But of course now the model is updated and "hey, i am changed so update again!" and again and again...

I only need the update to take place once. I think i need another approach, but can not figure out what to do.

Comment: How are you loading the data?

Comment: Ow, my head hurts. It must be the hot weather lately... I can of course just add another var with the needed value and get that in the process of my get data get factory. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can unregister a `$watch`

```
var unregister = scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
    if (shouldStopWatching) {
        unregister();
    }
});
```

where `shouldStopWatching` is whatever condition you need (i.e. stop on second call of callback etc)